# Get posts with tags having a column value not more than 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Say, I have two entities in many-to-many relationship:

```
posts

-id
-title    
-body
```

---

```
tags

-id  
-title
-sequence (int)
```

---

```
post_tag

-post_id
-tag_id
```

I want to grab those Posts which have the tags with the last `sequence` value of `7`. Bear with me. An example will make more sense:

```
post_tag:
=========
-post_id: 1
-tag_id: 3

-post_id: 1
-tag_id: 4
tags:
=====
-id: 3
-sequence: 2

-id: 4
-sequence: 7

 Post ID 1 should be returned
```

---

```
post_tag:
=========
-post_id: 2
-tag_id: 4

-post_id: 2
-tag_id: 5
tags:
=====
-id: 4
-sequence: 7

-id: 5
-sequence: 8

Post ID 2 should NOT be returned because it has a tag whose sequence exceeds 7.
```

---

```
post_tag:
=========
-post_id: 3
-tag_id: 2

-post_id: 3
-tag_id: 3

-post_id: 3
-tag_id: 4
tags:
=====
-id: 2
-sequence: 1

-id: 3
-sequence: 2

-id: 4
-sequence: 7

 Post ID 3 should be returned
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q){ $q->where('sequence', 7);})->get();
```

But it returns even those posts whose sequence is upper than 7. And I am not complaining. I know why it returns the posts with tags having sequence greater than 7. I just don't know how to solve this.

Hint: In terms of query, the problem can be thought of as:

> Not more than X and X inclusive

Comment: You say when you ran the command above you got even the results which `sequence` was bigger than `7`?

Comment: @NikolaGavric yes. That's because post_tag table already had such posts whose tags consisted of sequence 7 and 7+.

Comment: But what I need is posts whose tags consist of 7 and 7-

Comment: So everything below 7 and 7 inclusive?

Comment: Exactly. What @TharakaDilshan suggested below ignores 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what you are looking for is `whereDoesntHave()`

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function ($q) {
        $q->where('sequence', 7);
    })
    ->whereDoesntHave('tags', function($q) {
        $q->where('sequence', '>', 7);
    })->get();
```

Comment: It even returns those posts that do not have tags with sequence 7.

Comment: I Updated the answer

Comment: after I reading the other question comment you have put, I understood your scenario, now check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is a check for equality and less than, like this:

`$posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) {
    $q->where('sequence', '<=', 7);
})->get();`

Comment: It would return those posts that have tags that do not contain sequence 7. But existence of sequence 7 is a `must` in my scenario. The condition is this: Posts with tags that `must` have sequence value 7 and `must not` have sequence value more than 7.